# Pretty interesting question regarding address book in iPhone

Tags: iphone

HI all i have seen the example of apple name as 'QUICK CONTACTS' and here is an error in the 
person view controller. here it always show same data with two names

```
// Fetch the address book 
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
// Search for the person named "Appleseed" in the address book
NSArray *people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR("Appleseed"));
// Display "Appleseed" information if found in the address book 
if ((people != nil) && [people count])
{
    ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[*people objectAtIndex:0*];
    ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    picker.personViewDelegate = self;
    picker.displayedPerson = person;
    // Allow users to edit the person’s information
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

here it always show same information for two person with same name how can we remove this error.

Comment: what error? That you can't choose between 'john appleseed' and 'hugo appleseed'? This is because it's a example that should give you a *quick* (hence the name) overview about whatever viewcontroller this is. You are encouraged to extend the examples to your needs. And depending on your needs you want to throw an error if there are two persons with the same name, you want to show a picker where you can select one or you can select the right one by code. It's up to you.

Comment: `[*people objectAtIndex:0*]`???

Answer (score 0):

quite confused with what you wanna ask.. if you are getting same data that means you the same data feed in two times ..are you working on a simulator ?

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, not an answer